# How to determine the row number of a listview when the user clicks with the mouse on an object? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-listview

I have a listView as below.

```html
  <ListView
            Margin ="5"
            Name="dgListaProductosPromociones"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            Grid.Row="4">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View >
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  Width="220" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Color" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding color}" />
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Width="20" Height="20" MouseUp="mouseUpEditProduct" Source="/Images/editN.png"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

The image inside the listView has the mouseUpEditProduct event:

```js
 private void mouseUpEditProduct(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

My question is: How can I determine in the mouseUpEditProduct function which row of the listView belongs the image that has been clicked by the mouse?

Comment: I'd rather subscribe to `SelectionChanged` event and then in the event handler I can get `int selectedIndex = (sender as ListView).SelectedIndex;`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for writing:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set as an instance of an object.'

(... as System.Windows.Controls.ListView) returned null.

Comment: The cast is returning null since most likely you haven't moved your event handler from `Image` to the `ListView` yet. Once you do it, the sender will be the `ListView` and the cast becomes valid. I was about to explain that in the answer, unfortunately the question got closed before I managed to.

Comment: As someone has indicated above, there is another related thread and the solution is like this:

  var tb = (Image) e.OriginalSource;
             var dataCxtx = tb.DataContext;

where dataCxtx contains all the characteristics of the elements in the ListView row.

Comment: The other thread answers how to get the object selected itself. You're asking about the index of the object in the whole collection of the objects. Or am I missing something? By the way, If you change your mind you can still use my approach, only then invoke `var selectedItem = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;` with desired casting probably.